# Can /bin/bash -c export variable to parent shell

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying to run arbitrary bash commands in the shell, but I can only access the shell buy running `/bin/bash -c`

Is there anyway of being able to run something like:

`/bin/bash -c "export FOO=bar"`

and then see FOO set in the original shell?

Comment: But... from where are you doing `/bin/bash -c` then?

Comment: from inside a programming language. and running commands like `source` or `eval` or other bash commands that are not files on the filesystem, like functions etc can't be called directory from this programming language.

Comment: In general, no, a child cannot change the environment of the parent directly.  There may be other ways to accomplish what you want to do though if you give more details on what you're goal is (e.g., you might able to do `FOO=$(bash -c "echo bar")` or something similar, though it's not recommended to use all upper case for your variable names lest you collide with special builtin ones.

Answer (score 3):

No.

This isn't shell-specific -- no UNIX process can change a parent process's environment variables without that parent process honoring an interface (for instance, reading new variables/values from stdout), or using unreliable and unsupportable hackery (like attaching to the parent process with a debugger and calling `setenv()` directly).

Consider `ssh-agent` as an example:

```
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/var/folders/t2/t58p1nwx1g38tkhykqfhvmm80000gn/T//ssh-0HSNi1V5h9wf/agent.17313; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=17314; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 17314;
```

...thus, documented for use with a pattern akin to:

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```

In this case, that interface is `eval`-able shell code; however, as this is trivially used to execute arbitrary commands, supporting this interface is a security risk.

---

Inasmuch as your goal is to use the result of shell commands to modify the environment of a program that isn't a shell language at all, and thus doesn't support `eval` or `source`, this gives you the ability to use a safer stream format, such as a NUL-delimited stream. For instance, if your shell program writes `key=val\0` pairs, with literal `NUL` characters for `\0`, you can do something akin to the following in Python:

```
for env_val in s.split('\0'):
  if not env_val.contains('='): continue
  k, v = env_val.split('=', 1)
  environ[k] = v
```

...ported to your language of choice. To write in this format from shell:

```
printf '%s=%s\0' "$key" "$val"
```

...will suffice.